# Rewrite rule for my own PHP file in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, file, url-rewriting, rule

i have problem. I have my own PHP file in Wordpress and i can use him on URL for example:
http://www.domain.tld/wp-content/themes/theme/filter.php?foo=arg1&fo=arg2

But i wanna use this file on URLs like http://www.domain.tld/filter/arg1/arg2/. Is it possible?

Thank you!

Comment: Since you tagged it as [rewrite], you already know that you need to use mod_rewrite. Did you look for mod_rewrite guides? What have you tried?

Comment: I tried htaccess examples (http://codex.wordpress.org/User:Amereservant/Editing_and_Customizing_htaccess_Indirectly) and this http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/5413/need-help-with-add-rewrite-rule but i don't know where do i have to insert code. In functions.php is inactive.

Comment: create a plugin for it is the way most would do it

Comment: @user3858685 Then you should add these details to the question, they'll help future readers to better identify the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [add_rewrite-rule()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule)
Something like this:

```
add_rewrite_rule(
        '^filter/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?',
        'wp-content/themes/theme/filter.php?foo=$matches[1]&fo=$matches[2]',
        'top'
        );

add_rewrite_tag('%foo%', '([^&]+)');
add_rewrite_tag('%fo%', '([^&]+)');
```

then in filter.php, you will need to use `get_query_var` rather than normal php `$_GET`, eg:

```
//echo $_GET['foo']; wont work
echo get_query_var('foo');
```

Comment: Thank you, but when i put this code to the functions.php nothing will hapen. Where do I insert this code? Is functions.php right destination?

Comment: Real example: I have this php file: http://www.collegesnearme.org/wp-content/themes/flatads/filter.php?foo=filip&fo=petr and it brings me correct result. But with your code in functions.php is result on http://www.collegesnearme.org/filter/filip/peter/ same as before :-(

Comment: Yes, put this into your functions.php file, then flush the rewrite rules by logging into the backend and visiting the permalinks settings page.

Comment: Last thing - when i'm using this, i dont see my variables - only $matches[1]. Why? Example: http://www.collegesnearme.org/filter/filip/

Comment: OK, having looked into it, its a little more complicated. See my edit, and this article is worth a look: http://www.paulund.co.uk/rewrite-urls-wordpress